# What is the typical amount of full length clones in a cDNA library?

Tags: molecular-biology, lab-techniques, cloning, cdna

For a Yeast Two Hybrid project we need to make a cDNA library from a single celled organism. We used the Cloneminer II kit from Thermo. We followed the manual and performed all the quality control steps and everything checked out. However out of curiosity we sent 10 individual colonies for sequencing and while all of those give hits in our organism only 40% seem to be even approaching full length in the coding sequence (80-90% coverage).

Is this normal or did we have poor input material/made a mistake? What is the average number of full length clones for a typical cDNA library?